# How to get a reference to the currently focused form field in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, cross-browser

I'm looking for a cross-browser method - I know IE has something (I've already forgotten what), and the way to do it in Mozilla may have to do with a focusNode thing I found, that seems related to getting text selections.

Methods involving jQuery or another common JS library are fine by me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [extra selectors plugin](http://www.softwareunity.com/sandbox/JQueryMoreSelectors/) for [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), it includes a `:focus` selector that answers your need. You can use just the implementation of that selector if you don't the rest.

Answer (score 1):

OK then, so use jQuery.

There is no current, available way to just ask this. You need to track the focus events when they happen, so this sample (thanks to Karl Rudd [here](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/e31e21ba4ef3160c/21c2d4c016336fad?lnk=raot&pli=1)) does that across all elements. This is for inputs but you can adjust the selector to fit your needs, even across the entire DOM.

```
var currentFocus = null; 
$(':input').focus( function() { 
    currentFocus = this; 
}).blur( function() { 

    currentFocus = null; 
});
```